# U+0008 Character added to string in certain browsers

Tags: php, mysql

I have a comments section on my website. These comments are stored in a MySQL database in a field with a 'text'-datatype and the latin1_swedish_ci collation. When I echo the result of a query to display the comments, the character U+0008 (backspace) is displayed in Firefox, Opera and other browsers. Chrome ignores this and just displays white space. Is there any way to remove this character?

**Edit:**
I have two sections on the website, one where I post notifications and one where users post comments. The 'message'-fields that contain the content are identically configured and echoed. As I said, it doesn't make a difference wether I post comments via the site, or via a direct query. Remarkably, ne comment that has an -tag at the end doesn't have the U+0008 character appended to it.

Comment: You should NOT remove this. You should find where it comes from, and fix there.

Comment: I'll try adding a value manually, probably it's caused by the form or submission...

Comment: btw: why you use latin1 encoding?

Comment: This was set by default by my host, I didn't change anything about that. I tried adding a value by executing a query manually, but the error persists, so it should either be an error in the database or a php error. I'll try some more thing in the meantime...

Comment: "This was set by default by my host" - i do not get it. You have to have control on both database encoding AND connection encoding or you end with garbage

Comment: I didn't change the encoding, but just used the default. Of course I'm able to change it, but I didn't until I ran into this issue. The issue appeared not to be in the database though, it was some normal looking whitespace in my code that was causing problems..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the collation in MySQL from `latin1_swedish_ci` to unicode and try. Could be that the data while being entered is encoded in unicode, but while getting stored in the DB loses the encoding and shows up the backspace in unicode string. However you will need to find out where it comes from as @WebnetMobile.com suggested

Comment: Tried that too, but that doesn't make a difference. I have two sections on the website, one where I post notifications and one where users post comments. The 'message'-fields that contain the content are identically configured and echoed. As I said, it doesn't make a difference wether I post comments via the site, or via a direct query. Remarkably, ne comment that has an <a>-tag at the end doesn't have the U+0008 character appended to it.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced a space in my `echo` function. This apparantly solved the issue. I really don't know how that could fix it, but the `U+0008` characters are all gone...

Comment: How was that space being generated? And did you do a plain str_replace to remove it?

Comment: I didn't have to do anything, probably there was something messed up with my keyboard or something must have been wrong with the encoding of the code editor on my C-panel which I used once, since there was a backspace character in my code that looked like whitespace in Webmatrix. When I rewrote the line, the issue was fixed like magic ;)

Comment: well..sounds like black magic to me! ;) anyways, glad it worked out for you

Comment: @Raidenace sure does, I'll mark your answer as the right one, since that might help out others having the same problem more than the answer, which is only specific to my case ;)